# How to convert Sharepoint 2010 Chart web part to Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-services, chart-web-part, chart

I want to convert chart webpart's chart to excel format
how it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what its worth, whatever the data you are pulling from to make the chart needs to be in Excel for that to be possible. So, if the chart is generated from a SharePoint list, you need to export that Sharepoint list into an Excel Spreadsheet, save it and upload it back into SharePoint via document library. That way you can work with the data in Excel and create Charts in Excel with it and use the Excel Web App to display the charts in SharePoint.

Comment: Chart is not getting generated from Sharepoint list directly. chart webpart is connected to another webpart created using visual studio, that web part provides data to chart. Now i want that chart should get converted to Excel format.

Comment: The OOTB Chart web part does not allow conversions to any other format.

Comment: Is there no way to convert it? like clicking on button chart will export to excel?

Comment: No. There are third party chart solutions that provide that. Just an example: http://store.bamboosolutions.com/sharepoint-chart-plus-web-part.aspx